# Is this mold in our windows?

Tags: windows

There’s this dark stuff that is caked in some of the windows on our house.

I am not sure if it’s dirt/debris that got in there or if it is mold. Also don’t know what that part of the window is called.

Is there any way to take that apart and clean them or do I just have to replace?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the dark material between the two panes of double pane windows? How many windows are affected? Where is this house located? Is it in a warm, humid climate? Surrounded by trees?

Comment: We need a few more pictures.

Comment: Added more pics

Answer (score 4):

The answer is - **it doesn't matter**.

Whether the debris is grime and dirt or mold...

1. It won't "hurt" you as there is a glass barrier in between.
2. There isn't a different way to handle it.
3. As a typical home owner without industrial tools, you really have no way of resealing your windows.

So basically a seal has failed on your window.   You can either replace that part of the window (frame and all).  For that part you will need to know manufacturing details to assure a proper guide fit.   More than likely only that manufacture (not all cases) can reproduce.

The other option is take that part of the window out, and either take it to a window or glass shop.   They can take window apart and reseal it.   Just FWIW I usually tend to order a replacement as I have found that when getting a window resealed for some reason I don't see the quality compared to the window going through the normal "manufacturing" process.   Usually the costs are close and obviously this is locality and opinion based.   If there was a glass shop down the street that would offer a 5 year warranty I would go with that - mine won't.

Comment: I'll also point out that there are some companies who claim to be able to evacuate and re-seal such windows.  I have never used such a service and so I can't comment on how effective it is.  But it might be useful have have one of them take a look.

Comment: @jwh20 - yes but this is where it is probably just easier to call manufacturer.   If this company comes out to your house to evaluate one window and then have you do whatever with the window, their cost to fix will certainly be just as much as replacement.   Only bring-it-in places are cheaper.

Comment: Before doing anything else, check whether the manufacturer's warranty applies. Some have lifetime warranties against leakage.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg - yes these are all over the place.  Some have lifetime, some just for original owner but worth the check.  I had a window fail in a rental exactly like this and was super super surprised that window world (yes the HF of windows) sent me a new bottom piece.

Comment: Less concerned with it harming us, more so with the windows having bad seals and not doing thier jobs keeping cold/heat in. The piece in question looks like it could simply pop off, be cleaned, then reattached. It’s like this on several windows though.

Comment: @EMAW2008 - you are kind of missing the point of my answer.   You can't reseal a window yourself.   You can spend a lot of time popping it off and cleaning it, putting it back together and it will look like that again in 2 months.